# Xcode: How to switch to another window using TableView?

Tags: xcode

the error ---> when i click the name the application crashes...
rectification---> when i click the name in table it should jump to another view...

my code is

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [ListArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ListData *oList = [[ListData alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListData" bundle:nil];
    NSString *psCatId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row+1];
    oList.psId = psCatId;
    [self presentModalViewController:oList animated:YES];
    [oList release];    
}
```

Comment: What does the crash say?

Comment: i got it, it was just a database trouble.... thank u